# Prove that $x\mapsto \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}f_n(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ does not converge uniformly on $[-1,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

For each $n,$ we define \begin{align} f_n:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} \end{align}
\begin{align} x\mapsto f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\end{align}
We consider the function 
\begin{align} f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} \end{align}
\begin{align} x\mapsto f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}f_n(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\end{align}

I want to show that the series does not converge uniformly on $[-1,1]$ but I'm finding it difficult to do that.

First of all, I considered the Weierstrass M test.

**MY TRIAL**

\begin{align}\left|f_n(x)\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} ,\;\;\forall \;x\in[-1,1],\;\forall\;n\in\Bbb{N}\end{align}

I'm also thinking that the $\beta_n=\sup\limits_{x\in[-1,1]}|\sum^{n}_{i=0}f_i(x)-\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}f_i(x)|$ approach could be very helpful too!

Comment: Do you have to prove that the **sequence** $f_n$ converges (this is what you say in the title) or that the **series** $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ converges?

Comment: @5xum: The series!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convergence is not uniform.

For $x \ne 0$ this is a geometric series:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} = x^2\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac1{1+x^2}}= x^2+1$$

and for $x = 0$ the sum is $0$.

Therefore

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2+1, &\text{ if } x \ne 0\\
0, &\text{ if }x = 0
\end{cases}$$

Since $f$ is not continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have shown this before now. I want to show that the series converges uniformly on $[-1,1]$ and not on $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @Micheal The convergence is not uniform on $[-1,1]$ so it can't be shown. The sum is the same on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I was thinking so. Is it because of the discontinuity at $0$?

Comment: @Micheal Yes, uniform limit of continuous functions has to be continuous.

Comment: If  convergence is  uniform on  $[-1,1]$,  sum function $f$ must be continuous!

Comment: @mechanodroid: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt!

Comment: Same thing. On $[-1, 1]\setminus \{0\}$ the series converges to $1+x^2$ but at $0$ the series converges to $0$. Thus $f$ is not continuous, and the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: Thanks all! Let me change the topic for future purpose!